# Error : Access denied When creating AWS custom resource

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I'm trying to create a custom resource for adding inventory configuration to bucket using cdk
i'm calling putBucketInventoryConfiguration() - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketInventoryConfiguration-property
 but I am getting access denied 
policy for destination bucket-

```
        config_inventory_role.add_to_policy(iam.PolicyStatement(
        effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        resources=[f'{config_inventory_bucket.bucket_arn}/*'],
        actions=['s3:PutObject'],
        conditions={"ArnLike": {
            "aws:SourceArn": config_upload_bucket.bucket_arn
        },
            "StringEquals": {
            "aws:SourceAccount": [
                kwargs["env"]["aws"]["account"]
            ],
            "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
        }
        }
    ))
```

> 

```
(iotsysteminventoryc231de866a82512a9a84151e276042845F52818C) Failed to create resource. Access Denied

[2020-06-15T08:23:51.589Z]  new CustomResource (/tmp/jsii-kernel-ymFU82/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/custom-resource.js:23:25)

[2020-06-15T08:23:51.589Z]  \_ new AwsCustomResource (/tmp/jsii-kernel-ymFU82/node_modules/@aws-cdk/custom-resources/lib/aws-custom-resource/aws-custom-resource.js:130:31)

[2020-06-15T08:23:51.589Z]  \_ /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7853:49

[2020-06-15T08:23:51.589Z]  \_ Kernel._wrapSandboxCode (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:8313:20)

[2020-06-15T08:23:51.589Z]  \_ Kernel._create (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7853:26)

[2020-06-15T08:23:51.589Z]  \_ Kernel.create (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7600:21)

[2020-06-15T08:23:51.589Z]  \_ KernelHost.processRequest (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7388:28)

[2020-06-15T08:23:51.589Z]  \_ KernelHost.run (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7328:14)

[2020-06-15T08:23:51.589Z]  \_ Immediate._onImmediate (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7331:37)

[2020-06-15T08:23:51.589Z]  \_ processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
```

Comment: Does your lambda has execution role with permission to modify s3 buckets? Also can you provide full error message?

Comment: It has all resource access

Comment: Does it try to create the stack ? Maybe CloudFormation console has more useful info?

Comment: Same error is being displayed in the cloud formation

Comment: can you try actions=['s3:*'] ?

Comment: @Marc I tried that but it was no help

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the exact same issue, did you find a solution.

```
new AwsCustomResource(this, 'ExportTaskDefToS3', {
   onUpdate: {
      service: 'S3',
      action: 'putObject',
      parameters: {
        ...s3params
      },
      physicalResourceId: PhysicalResourceId.of('ExportTaskDefToS3')
   },
   policy: AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromStatements([
    new PolicyStatement({
      actions: ["s3:*"],
      resources: [`${props.sourceBucketArn}/*`],
    }),
  ])
});
```

**Found the solution for my issue**->

The custom resource I am creating is in Account B.
S3 bucket is in account A. I had to update the S3 bucket policy in Account A.

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB:user/AccountBUserName"
},
"Action": [
"s3:GetObject",
"s3:PutObject",
"s3:PutObjectAcl"
],
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:s3:::AccountABucketName/*"
]
}
]
}